# Importing a newly created component gives error "module has no exported member"

Tags: angular

I have an existing Angular application, when I try to create new component and use it by importing into another `xyz.component.ts` it gives me the error-> "*module has no exported member".*

```
import { CreateEnvironmentDialog } from '../create-environment-dialog/create-environment-dialog.component';
```

Comment: Did you try to import 'CreateEnvironmentDialog' component inside a component that is in another module?

Comment: Try adding this new component in exports array of its module. This may be because both component are not in same module

Comment: More code would be nice otherwise we all have to guess and ask questions. Post code for your module(s), components, etc. If possible create a Stackblitz.. Thx

Comment: Check that your component is in `declarations` in `.module.ts`. Also check that your component class precedes with `export`

Answer (score 0):

To export a component you need explicitly write a component name in `exports` section. For example:

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
     YourComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    FormsModule
  ],
  exports: [
    YourComponent,
    FormsModule,
    CustomFormsModule
  ],
  providers: [
      YourService
  ]
})
export class SharedModule { }
```